# IE silently switches from https to http

Tags: ssl-certificate, internet-explorer-11

IE 11 suddenly started having problems with my website's SSL certificate. At least I assume that's what it is, because it just silently switches from https to http without giving any error messages. Other browsers don't have any problems with the certificate, and the certificate didn't change, so I assume this is some IE update that broke it. I've tried adding the site to the trusted sites list, clearing SSL cache, nothing helps. Windows logs don't show any errors. There might be some insecure content on the page but this comes from ads and I can't change it; anyway, the worst this can do should be not showing insecure content?  What else could this be? You can see the example at https://www.windows2universe.org/php/registration/reg_login_und.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it could be a permanent redirection issue. try to open your website using Private Mode and see what happens.

UPDATE
Actually I checked your website, when I try to open it with HTTPS it returns a 301 (Permanent Redirection) to the HTTP version. check ur server configurations.

Comment: Gosh, you're right, it never actually occurred to me to check htaccess file! There were some suspicious lines, wonder if hackers did this. Thank you!

Comment: Great, vote up and accept the answer if it helped :)